# Unpivotting multiple columns - substring of column name as a new column with CROSS APPLY

Tags: sql-server, unpivot, cross-apply

I have a table with the following format

```
YEAR, MONTH, ITEM,  REQ_QTY1, REQ_QTY2 , ....REQ_QTY31 ,CONVERTED1, CONVERTED2 ....CONVERTED31
```

Where the suffix of each column is the day of the month.

I need to convert it to the following format, where Day_of_month is the numeric suffix of each column

```
YEAR, MONTH, DAY_OF_MONTH, ITEM, REQ_QTY, CONVERTED
```

I thought of using CROSS APPLY to retrieve the data, but I can't use CROSS APPLY to get the "Day of Month"

```
SELECT A.YEAR, A.MONTH, A.ITEM, B.REQ_QTY, B.CONVERTED
FROM TEST A
CROSS APPLY
(VALUES
   (REQ_QTY1, CONVERTED1),
 (REQ_QTY2, CONVERTED2),
 (REQ_QTY3, CONVERTED3),
......
 (REQ_QTY31, CONVERTED31)
 )B (REQ_QTY, CONVERTED)
```

The only way I found is to use a nested select with inner join

```
SELECT A.YEAR, A.MONTH,  A.DAY_OF_MONTH,  A.ITEM,A.REQ_QTY, D.CONVERTED FROM
  (SELECT YEAR, MONTH, ITEM, SUBSTRING(DAY_OF_MONTH,8,2) AS DAY_OF_MONTH, REQ_QTY FROM TEST 
  UNPIVOT
     (REQ_QTY FOR DAY_OF_MONTH IN ([REQ_QTY1],[REQ_QTY2],[REQ_QTY3],......[REQ_QTY30],[REQ_QTY31])
     ) B
  ) A
  INNER JOIN (SELECT YEAR, MONTH, ITEM, SUBSTRING(DAY_OF_MONTH,10,2) AS DAY_OF_MONTH, CONVERTED FROM TEST 
  UNPIVOT
     (CONVERTED FOR DAY_OF_MONTH IN ([CONVERTED1],[CONVERTED2],[CONVERTED3],....[CONVERTED30],[CONVERTED31])
     ) C
  ) D
  ON D.YEAR = A.YEAR AND D.MONTH = A.MONTH AND D.ITEM = A.ITEM AND D.DAY_OF_MONTH = A.DAY_OF_MONTH
```

Is there a way to use CROSS APPLY and yet get the DAY_OF_MONTH out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a way using CROSS APPLY, but instead of taking a substring, I'm basically hardcoding the days. Works well enough so...

```
SELECT A.YEAR, A.MONTH, A.ITEM, B.DAY_OF_MONTH, B.REQ_QTY, B.CONVERTED
FROM TEST A
CROSS APPLY
(
  VALUES
  ('01', REQ_QTY1, CONVERTED1),
  ('02', REQ_QTY2, CONVERTED2),
  ('03', REQ_QTY3, CONVERTED3),
  ('04', REQ_QTY4, CONVERTED4),
   ......
  ('31', REQ_QTY31, CONVERTED31)
  ) B (DAY_OF_MONTH, REQ_QTY, CONVERTED)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution with `CROSS APPLY` but it will definitely make it a bit faster as it uses a bit simpler approach and simpler execution plan.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/239be/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Test_Table([YEAR] INT, [MONTH] INT, [ITEM] INT,  REQ_QTY1 INT
       , REQ_QTY2 INT ,REQ_QTY3 INT , CONVERTED1 INT, CONVERTED2 INT, CONVERTED3 INT)
INSERT INTO Test_Table VALUES 
( 2015 ,  1 , 1 , 10 , 20 , 30 , 100 , 200 , 300),
( 2015 ,  2 , 1 , 10 , 20 , 30 , 100 , 200 , 300), 
( 2015 ,  3 , 1 , 10 , 20 , 30 , 100 , 200 , 300)
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
 (
    SELECT [YEAR] 
          ,[MONTH] 
          ,ITEM
          ,Vals
          ,CASE WHEN LEFT(N,3) = 'REQ' THEN SUBSTRING(N,8 ,2)
                WHEN LEFT(N,3) = 'CON' THEN SUBSTRING(N,10,2)
           END AS Day_Of_Month
          ,CASE WHEN LEFT(N,3) = 'REQ' THEN LEFT(N,7)
                WHEN LEFT(N,3) = 'CON' THEN LEFT(N,9)
           END AS Tran_Type
    FROM Test_Table t
      UNPIVOT (Vals FOR N IN ([REQ_QTY1],[REQ_QTY2],[REQ_QTY3],
                                            [CONVERTED1],[CONVERTED2],[CONVERTED3]))up
 )t2
PIVOT (SUM(Vals)
       FOR Tran_Type
       IN (REQ_QTY, CONVERTED))p
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/239be/1/0)**:

```
| YEAR | MONTH | ITEM | Day_Of_Month | REQ_QTY | CONVERTED |
|------|-------|------|--------------|---------|-----------|
| 2015 |     1 |    1 |            1 |      10 |       100 |
| 2015 |     1 |    1 |            2 |      20 |       200 |
| 2015 |     1 |    1 |            3 |      30 |       300 |
| 2015 |     2 |    1 |            1 |      10 |       100 |
| 2015 |     2 |    1 |            2 |      20 |       200 |
| 2015 |     2 |    1 |            3 |      30 |       300 |
| 2015 |     3 |    1 |            1 |      10 |       100 |
| 2015 |     3 |    1 |            2 |      20 |       200 |
| 2015 |     3 |    1 |            3 |      30 |       300 |
```